# Unable to use more than one service in component

Tags: angular

I'm just getting started with learning angular and web development in general. I'm trying to use the angular router to redirect after the form is submitted. But I'm getting an error on the second service that its not declared in the component. If I just have one it works
Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.css']
})
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, router: Router) { }
  onCreatePost(postData: { title: string; email: string; content: string }) {
    // Send Http request
    console.log(postData);
    this.http.post(' https://myapi/posts.json',postData)
    .subscribe();
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
   }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

error: Property 'router' does not exist on type 'QuestionComponent'.

Comment: Believe you are missing `private` : `private router: Router`

Comment: Ahh, that was it, I knew it would be something simple like that. Just had to add the private in again..  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your response as an answer so I can mark it as the resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `private router: Router` and it will work. use `public router: Router` if you want to use `router` in html template. If you declare it as `private` and that field is used in html somewhere AOT compiler will give you an error while building the project. Before ng 9 it wasn't giving any compile time error but I guess now we get compile time warning if we reference private field in html code of the component.

Answer (score 0):

Mayor your problem is because you router is not private here is a en example for more information https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-navigation-routerlink-navigate-navigatebyurl.amp

Comment: That doesn't explain why, nor the link helps. Parameter properties are declared by prefixing a constructor parameter with an accessibility modifier or readonly, or both. Using private for a parameter property declares and initializes a private member; likewise, the same is done for public, protected, and readonly. Straight from the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties